# Correct display of blf-text in Blender 3D viewport

Tags: 3d-view, bgl

Hello to all Blender enthusiasts! I have some questions about rendering text in viewports using the blf module. Here is my code:

```
import bpy
import blf

class DrawTextClass():

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.handle = None

    def draw_callback_px(self, context):
        font_id = 0
        blf.position(font_id, 1, 1, 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 4, 72)
        blf.draw(font_id, 'SOME TEXT HERE')

    def draw(self, context):
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_callback_px, (context,), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

    def remove_handle(self):
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')


drawtextclass = DrawTextClass(bpy.context)
dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
dns['drawtextclass'] = drawtextclass


class FontDrawerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.draw_exapmle_text'
    bl_label = 'test drawing operator'

    def execute(self, context):
        dns = bpy.app.driver_namespace
        drawtextclass = dns.get('drawtextclass')

        if drawtextclass.handle is not None:
            drawtextclass.remove_handle()
            drawtextclass.handle = None

            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif drawtextclass.handle == None:
            drawtextclass.draw(context)

            return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    register_class(FontDrawerOperator)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    unregister_class(FontDrawerOperator)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

1. When I run **FontDrawerOperator** and **drawtextclass.draw()** method is called with **blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)**, it draws this giant 170 meters text lying in the viewport.
   [image: blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)]

If I reduce the size in **blf.size(font_id, 4, 72)**, then I get this shimmery smudge. I
experimented with different values, but the text is either too large or small and blurry:
[image: blf.size(font_id, 4, 72)]

So what should I do to get small text to display normally?

2. How can I make the text always look at me in the viewport. Do I need additional methods for rotating and positioning text in screen space?
3. Is there a better way to place **remove_handle()** and **draw()** methods inside a **FontDrawerOperator** (not in **DrawTextClass**), to toggle drawing on and off without keeping track of the **DrawTextClass** instance every time via **bpy.app.driver_namespace**?
4. In order to draw the text and lines I need in the viewport, should I go deeper into learning opengl, as suggested in the official Blender documentation in the bgl section?

I apologize for the confusion, but the official documentation contains only simple examples and does not really explain anything. I would be happy to figure these out on my own, but the information on the Web is fragmented and scattered. Thanks!

Comment: I would also appreciate any help on this issue. May be you can find some good examples in the MeasureIt  tools addon, it ships with blender. Its basically a huge library of opengl drawing functions. I've tried to hack it in order to use it for my needs but its too complex for me. Let me know if you get any light on this.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch I've made good progress on this problem and preparing to give a detailed answer in the coming days 

Comment: Any news on that detailed answer??

Comment: Give a sec, by the will of fate, I returned to this problem, I’ll answer a little later